# regular expression works in validator, doesn't work in java code

Tags: java, android, regex

I have problem with this regular expression for checking email address `^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$`

I've tried in this regular expression validator: https://regex101.com and works without problem, however in java when I added backslashes like that `"^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$"` it doesn't work.

For matching I'm using this code:

```
public boolean validateEmail(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: In short what you want is email validation ?

Comment: You must have forgotten `/i` modifier.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev, it works when I changed pattern to "^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$" and used Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE)

Answer (score 1):

To use a case-insensitive modifier in a regex, you can either compile the pattern with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` or use an inline modifier `(?i)` at the start of the pattern.

```
String email_pattern = "(?i)^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$"
```

or

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

**Note that all case-insensitive Android regexps are Unicode aware**. See [Android regex syntax reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Note that on Android, `UNICODE_CASE` is always on: case-insensitive matching will always be Unicode-aware.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code for email string validation .

```
private boolean isValidEmaillId(String email) {

    return Pattern
            .compile(
                    "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$")
            .matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Comment: I need to use strict Pattern, cause backend use the same. Anyway thank you for your help.